# Reverse cluster analysis; identifying empty space or a lack of density in R with longitude and latitude?

Tags: r, gis, spatial, rgdal

I'm working on a project where I have a very large amount of points and I am looking to identify regions (defined by a lack of clustering) where the density of these points is statistically significantly less relative to others. Normally a visual would be enough but I have so many points that it is to difficult to tell where these empty spaces are and a density heat map doesn't help me zero in on smaller regions. Maybe I'm missing something very simpler here, but I am hoping someone can at least send me in the right direction of where to look. Below is a reproducible sample quick and dirty lets take these points from open data and map them to the borough file for NYC:

```
#libraries--------------------------

library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(sp)
library(jsonlite)
library(RJSONIO)
library(rgdal)

#call api data--------------------------

df =  fromJSON("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/24t3-xqyv.json?$query= SELECT Lat, Long_")
df <- data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(df),nrow=length(unlist(df[1])))))
names(df)[names(df) == 'X2'] = 'x'
names(df)[names(df) == 'X1'] = 'y'
df = df[, c("x", "y")]
df$x = as.numeric(as.character(df$x))
df$y = as.numeric(as.character(df$y))
df$x = round(df$x, 4)
df$y = round(df$y, 4)
df$x[df$x < -74.2] = NA
df$y[df$y < 40.5] = NA
df = na.omit(df)

#map data----------------------------


cd = readOGR("nybb.shp", layer = "nybb")
cd = spTransform(cd, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
cd_f = fortify(cd)


#map data
nyc = ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, 
                   y=lat, group=group), fill='grey', 
               size=.2,color='black', data=cd_f, alpha=1)


nyc + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), data = df, size = 1)

#how would I go about finding the empty spaces? That is the regions where there are no clusters?
```

In this case there aren't a lot of points but for the sake of demonstration, how would I:

1. identify pockets of low density
2. potentially draw polygon boundaries on those pockets?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

One way to get polygonal areas of low density would be to construct the
Dirichlet/Voronoi tesselation and choose the largest ones.

Below I use `spatstat` and `deldir` (loaded by `spatstat`) to do this.
It is not so fast so with many more points I don't know how well it will
go.

To use the results in `ggmap` and other spatial packages you can convert
back from `owin` and `ppp` to the spatial classes from `sp` and use
`spTransform` to get lat, long coordinates.

First load the packages:

```
library(maptools)
library(spatstat)
library(jsonlite)
```

Map and points in coordinates of shapefile (note I read in data from
local files downloaded from www):

```
cd = readOGR("nybb.shp", layer = "nybb")
#> OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
#> Source: "nybb.shp", layer: "nybb"
#> with 5 features
#> It has 4 fields
df <- fromJSON("NYC_data.json")
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(as.numeric(unlist(df)), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
df <- df[, c(2, 1)]
names(df) <- c("x", "y")
df <- df[df$x > -74.2 & df$y > 40.5, ]
coordinates(df) <- ~x+y
proj4string(df) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
df2 <- spTransform(df, proj4string(cd))
```

Switch to `spatstat` classes:

```
cd2 <- as(cd, "SpatialPolygons")
W <- as(cd2, "owin")

X <- as(df2, "ppp")
Window(X) <- W

plot(X, main = "")
```

[image]

Compute Dirichlet tessellation and areas and plot the tessellation:

```
d <- dirichlet(X)
#> Warning: 96 duplicated points were removed
a <- tile.areas(d)
plot(d, main = "")
```

[image]

Combine the `n_areas` biggest areas of the tessellation:

```
n_areas <- 30
empty <- tess(tiles = d$tiles[tail(order(a), n = n_areas)])
empty2 <- as.owin(empty)
```

Plot the result:

```
plot(W, main = "")
plot(empty2, col = "red", add = TRUE)
plot(X, add = TRUE)
```

[image]